# Caddy not redirecting https:// to https://www

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

My Caddy config does not redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

However, if I just type http://example.com, it does the redirection correctly to https://www.example.com

Caddy file:

```
{
    debug
    email myemail@example.com
}

example.com {
    redir https://www.example.com{uri}
}

www.example.com {
    tls {
      on_demand
    }
    reverse_proxy docker:7000
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with Curl.  Sometimes browsers cache behaviour

Comment: @TobyAllen yes I did. Same thing. I also tried from mobile, different browsers and VPN.